# Redirecting to specific part of React App, after a function executes successfully

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I built this React app where a user can delete a blog post and when they do I want to redirect them back to the /blog route. I tried window.location.href = '/blog' ... I tried window.location = "/blog" ....

Nothing seemed to work so far. Is there a specific to React way of doing that or am I just coding the wrong commands here?

Note: the whole function in this example takes the selected post, sends a delete request to the server, deletes it and then after successfully deleting it comes the redirect part of it, which I'm struggling to implement correctly.

Comment: Would you show readers your code, and show any errors/warnings you get on your JS console?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the router from BrowserRouter to Router passing in history you can then `push` the location you want.

```
# history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

export default createBrowserHistory()

# App.jsx
...
import history from './history'
....

<Router history={history}>
...
</Router>

# actions.js

export const deleteBlogPost = blogId => async dispatch => {
  await streams.delete(`/blogs/${ blogId }`)

  dispatch({ type: DELETE_BLOG, payload: blogId })
  history.push('/blogs')
}
```